# isPropablyReaderable returns true but no reader icon is shown in firefox

Tags: html

Since some days I'm trying to figure out why firefox is not showing the reader mode icon in the addressbar on my website.

The website is in an early alpha stage and just for experimental use I'm showing some headers, lists and "lorem-ipsum" paragraphs: https://riki.w00tserver.org

I have an `<article>` that holds all the content with `<p>` and so on. Everything I read already is inside - I really don't have an idea why it is not recognizing my content.

So I tried https://github.com/mozilla/readability - and it shows that my page `isPropablyReaderable`:

```js
jQuery('body').append('<script src="https://my-first-domain.de/Readability.js">');
jQuery('body').append('<script src="https://my-first-domain.de/Readability-readerable.js">')
var doc = document.cloneNode(true);
isProbablyReaderable(doc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is described anywhere but it seems that the front page of a domain never offers (or is rendered in readers) reading mode. Navigating to https://riki.w00tserver.org/home offers the reading mode, also mercury reader is not showing a warning and pocket is rendering the content correct.